# Extract Object (s)(data) using Value from JSON Object

Tags: json

Please share what are all the possible ways of extracting object(s) using value from a JSON Object. 
consider below JSON example :

```
{
"ProductCollection": [
    {
        "ProductId": "1239102",
        "Name": "Power Projector 4713",
        "Category": "Projector",
        "SupplierName": "Titanium",
        "Description": "A very powerful projector with special features for Internet usability, USB",
        "WeightMeasure": 1467,
        "WeightUnit": "g",
        "Price": 856.49,
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 3,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "Width": 51,
        "Depth": 42,
        "Height": 18,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "2212-121-828",
        "Name": "Gladiator MX",
        "Category": "Graphics Card",
        "SupplierName": "Technocom",
        "Description": "Gladiator MX: DDR2 RoHS 128MB Supporting 512MB Clock rate: 350 MHz Memory Clock: 533 MHz, Bus Type: PCI-Express, Memory Type: DDR2 Memory Bus: 32-bit Highlighted Features: DVI Out, TV Out , HDTV",
        "WeightMeasure": 321,
        "WeightUnit": "g",
        "Price": 81.7,
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Status": "Discontinued",
        "Quantity": 10,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "Width": 34,
        "Depth": 14,
        "Height": 2,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    }
]
}
```

If i input "Gladiator MX", I want whole object as below :

```
{
        "ProductId": "2212-121-828",
        "Name": "Gladiator MX",
        "Category": "Graphics Card",
        "SupplierName": "Technocom",
        "Description": "Gladiator MX: DDR2 RoHS 128MB Supporting 512MB Clock rate: 350 MHz Memory Clock: 533 MHz, Bus Type: PCI-Express, Memory Type: DDR2 Memory Bus: 32-bit Highlighted Features: DVI Out, TV Out , HDTV",
        "WeightMeasure": 321,
        "WeightUnit": "g",
        "Price": 81.7,
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Status": "Discontinued",
        "Quantity": 10,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "Width": 34,
        "Depth": 14,
        "Height": 2,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    }
```

Hope the question is clear.
TIA.

Comment: What language are you using? Java?

Comment: No.. I wanted in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First you would parse your JSON string into a Javascript object by using `JSON.parse`.

Now your problem is to find a specific object in an array of objects. You can use `filter`, or a manual `for` loop:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
var products = data["ProductCollection"];
var gladiatorMX;

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    var product = products[i];
    if (product["Name"] == "Gladiator MX") {
        gladiatorMX = product;
        break;
    }
}
```